# Synchronizing Unsubscribe/Subscribe from marketing cloud to salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

when we use V2 Connector the email Opt-out checkbox in salesforce is used to unsubscribe and subscribe the subscribers in marketing cloud and in V5 we are having the below scenario

we are unsubscribing the Subscriber(contact) going into particular contact page-layout(salesforce) and clicking unsubscribe custom link and the same is reflecting in to marketing cloud all subscribers that particular contact is unsubscribed with red mark.

In the same way when we go in to marketing cloud all subscribers and unsubscribing from marketing cloud its not reflecting back in to salesforce.

Is there anyway we can achieve this issue??

Thanks in advance

Regards
Viswanath

Comment: I believe if you change the subscriber status via the Standard Preference Center the statuses are kept in-sync.

Comment: If you use a Custom Preference Center, ampscript code would need to be added to update the Salesforce contact record.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the only way to achieve this globally (and without code) is to use the unsubscribe/resubscribe custom links. It sounds like you are already using this (included with the Installed Package). Even if you resubscribe the contact in Marketing Cloud, it will not share the update with the Email Opt Out field in Salesforce.

[image: Marketing Cloud Subscriptions Links]

Comment: Yes @chris, we even contacted support team for this they said it will not share update back to Email opt-out and the only way to do it is manual way that we need to go to salesforce and update

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Ampscript. Use the [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/updatesinglesalesforceobject52/) to update the PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail Field in Sales Cloud

Comment: A more detailed solution can be found here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247408/marketing-cloud-mc-connect-syncing-email-unsubscribes-with-sales-cloud-sc/247409#247409